# Prove $L^p$ ($1\leqslant p\leq +\infty)$ Norms on $C[0,1]$ are Not Equivalent

Tags: normed-spaces, lp-spaces

For $p<q$, using Holder inequality, I deduced that
$$
\int_{[0,1]}|f|^p dx = \int_{[0,1]}|f|^p\cdot 1dx
\leqslant\left(\int_{[0,1]}|f|^{p\cdot 
 {q\over p} } dx\right)^{p\over q}
\left(\int_{[0,1]}1^{
 q\over q-p } dx\right)^{q-p\over q}
=\left(\int_{[0,1]}|f|^q dx\right)^{p\over q},
$$
thus, $\Vert f\Vert_p\leqslant\Vert f\Vert_q$, which means $\Vert\cdot\Vert_p$ is weaker than $\Vert\cdot\Vert_q$.

I wish to figure out
(1) Whether my deduction was correct?
(2) How to further show that these two norms are not equivalent?
Note that the space is $C[0,1]$.

Comment: @Surb Your function is not quite in $C([0,1])$ :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Hint:- Do you know that $C[0,1]$ is dense in $L^{p}$ ? . Now do you see the problem?. $L^{p}$ is not equal to $L^{q}$ if $p\neq q $. But if norms are equivalent then what can you conclude using the density of $C[0,1]$?